# How to fix a ruined package catalog?

Tags: 11.10, apt, mono

After installing `mono-complete` on my Ubuntu 11.10, something got corrupted in the package catalog. Whenever I try to install\remove anything I get an error and told to use `apt-get -f install`. I get the same thing from the GUI. When I try to do it, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mono-devel mono-xbuild
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mono-devel mono-xbuild
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,256 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,048 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 269743 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mono-xbuild (from .../mono-xbuild_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-xbuild_2.10.5-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Unpacking mono-devel (from .../mono-devel_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-devel_2.10.5-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/mono/2.0/al.exe.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-xbuild_2.10.5-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-devel_2.10.5-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I understand that I'm missing some mono files\directories, but I can't reinstall mono because `apt-get` just tells me to run `apt-get -f install` - which doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

***UPDATE***
Running `apt-get update` gives me the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/edgy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/edgy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: hello ,have you tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure package_name if it doesnt work i would remove the config files and try over if not make sure that apt-get its workin correctly by installing sumtin else just to test , good luck

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` doesn't work - it tells me the package is broken. Where are those config files that I need to remove?

Comment: @Idan - why have you got "edgy" software-source?  Comment those out.  Also - the firefox PPA you have doesnt have an oneiric repo.  Comment those out as well.

Comment: Can you please pastebin your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: I don't think you have exactly that same problem, but instead of repairing the package database, you might want to try to recover it from a backup as explained [here](http://superuser.com/q/103289).

Comment: @jcollado: Thanks, I managed to recover the package catalog, but I still can't install mono-complete.

Comment: @PauloArruda: <http://pastebin.com/477x4PSD>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two last lines of your /etc/apt/sources.list are wrong. Remove it from the file:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu edgy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu edgy universe
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That should fix the problems. Let me know if it's solved!

Regards

Comment: That did not work - I still can't install mono-complete.

Comment: Can you post the result of your attempt to install it after fixing your sources.list?

Comment: Please, try this command: dpkg --configure -a

Comment: I tried to install it(after fixing sources.list and recovering the apt status file from the backup) and than tried `dpkg --configure -a`. The package catalog still gets corrupted. Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/2rjqZUkM

Comment: What happens if you try to purge (apt-get --purge remove mono-complete) and then autoremove unused packages (apt-get autoremove) and then try to install it again?

Comment: I can't even remove it - http://pastebin.com/vV952WjA  
The only way to remove it is to recover the status file from a backup.

Comment: Good, now remove monodoc-browser (sudo apt-get --purge remove monodoc-browser) and then clean (sudo apt-get clean) and try installing mono-complete again (without mono-browser)

Comment: Sorry i think i wasnt clear. According to your last pastebin, you did remove the package mono-complete, but apt was still trying to install mono-browser. Just follow the steps i wrote in the comment above.

Comment: When I try to remove `monodoc-browser` I get told I need to do `apt-get -f install`. The only way for me to remove `monodoc-browser` is to recover from a backup. When I try to install just `monodoc-browser`, I get the corruption errors.  

I don't suppose there is a way to install `mono-complete` without `mono-browser`? Is there another package that'll give me everything I need to develop in mono?

Comment: First, we need to solve this problem, or else you wont be able to install new packages in the right way. Try to remove those packages with "dpkg --purge mono-browser" and "dpkg --purge mono-complete". After that, try "dpkg --configure -a" and let me now how it goes.

Comment: I can't remove `monodoc-browser` - this is what I get - http://pastebin.com/4sLUdjPR . But that does not mean I can't recover from a backup. After I recover from a backup everything works as it should - as long as I don't try to install `monodoc-browser` or `mono-complete`.  So, there is no point to keep trying to remove `monodoc-browser` with the package manager, since we already tried that and in doesn't work, and we can reach the same state by recovering from a backup. I just need to know what to do after I recover from a backup to get the full mono SDK.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1850/discussion-between-paulo-arruda-and-idan-arye)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get update`

That will update your system software list.

And then,

`sudo apt-get install -f`

That should fix your packages.

If it doesn't, then you've got a broken package manager, and I'd recommend reinstalling - but **only** if you've tried everything else!!!

Comment: The update command give me errors(I updated them at the question), and the install fix command gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with firefox.

I got away with it by Editing the status file. Just remove the entry of the software causing trouble.

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I still cannot install firefox but at least installing other software is now possible. If you find a way to install the said package, please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the software that was not properly installed and throwing the error.
Re-install it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package> .  
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f
```

then proceed with the software you want to install.